# Bohr's Inequality

Tags: inequality

Can anyone point me to any reference on the following inequality:
Let $c>0, a,b \in \Bbb{R}$
$$
\|a+b\|^2 \leq (1+c)\|a\|^2+(1+{\textstyle\frac{1}{c}})\|b\|^2
$$

I'm not even sure if "Bohr's Inequality" is this inequality's name, since I can't find it anywhere in the internet.

I'm having a bad day and I got stuck in this one, apparently. Any suggestions or hints on how to prove it will be appreciated.

Comment: For a reference (but no proof), see Hardy, Littlewood, and Pólya's *Inequalities*, second edition, Problem #59 on page 61.  They do give Bohr as a reference for the inequality, and they also say that $a$ and $b$ could be real or complex.

Comment: Is there any online repository where I could look that up? It's a holyday in my country, so I can't go look at a library.

Comment: You should be able to access it via Google books: http://books.google.com/.  Just search for "Hardy, Littlewood, Polya."

Comment: Thanks, I had actually tried googling that book before to no avail, even thought it is in google's own network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint. $a,b$ and $c$ are real, and the inequality boils down to showing that

\begin{equation}
c|a|^2 + \frac{1}{c}|b|^2 -2ab \geq 0
\end{equation}

Consider the function

\begin{equation}
f(x) = x|a|^2 + \frac{1}{x}|b|^2 -2ab
\end{equation}

What is the minimum value of this function?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I forgot to state that I can't use derivatives here. I can't recall any way of showing the minimum value of a function without using derivatives.

Comment: After thinking a bit over your first hint, you can rearrange it to be $0 \leq \|a\|^2-\frac{2ab}{c} \|b\|^2 = (a-\frac{b}{c})^2$ which is true. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean

$$(a+b)^2 \le (1+c)a^2 + (1 + 1/c)b^2$$
?

This follows from $\text{AM} \ge \text{GM}$

$$ca^2 + b^2/c \ge 2 ab$$

No add $a^2 + b^2$ to both sides.

If you meant $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the Euclidean Norm, you can prove it by applying the above $n$ times.

Comment: Since a and b are real numbers, $\| \circ \|$ is the absolute value. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a remark/comment:*

The inequality you mention is perhaps be an due to Harald Bohr, there is however an other inequality usually called Bohr's inequality.

Consider a bounded analytic function $f$ on the unit disc, that is $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n\ \text{  and  }\ \|f\|_\infty=\sup_{|z|<1}|f(z)|<\infty.$$
Then for $0<r\le\frac{1}{3}$ we have (Bohr's inequality) 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|r^n\le \|f\|_\infty.$$
Moreover, the constant $\frac{1}{3}$ is the best possible which was actually not proved by Bohr but by *F.* Wiener.

H. P. Boas and D. Khavinson, *[Bohr's power series theorem in several
variables](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-97-04270-6)*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 125(1997), 2975-2979.

H. Bohr, *[A theorem concerning power series](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s2-13.1.1)*, Proc. London Math. Soc.
2(13)1914, 1-5.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks.  $\ \ \ $

Answer (score 0):

Start with 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( a\sqrt{c}-\frac{b}{\sqrt{c} } \right)^2 \geq 0. 
\end{eqnarray*}
Expand, rearrange, add $a^2+b^2$ to both sides and we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( a+b  \right)^2 \leq (1+c)a^2+ \left( 1+ \frac{1}{c} \right) b^2.  
\end{eqnarray*}